# How to wait for google spreadsheet call and set it inside of a for loop

Tags: node.js, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-nodejs-client

To get row from a google spreadsheet this code will work:

```
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    const numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
    console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
    //Here I can use my rows
  }
});
```

but how can I wait for this function to finish? Example:

```
console.log("1");
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("2");
  }
});
console.log("3");
```

This will most likely print 132. Also is there a way to get the result and err outside of the current scope?

pseudo code from what I possible mean (should print 123):

```
console.log("1"); //Print 1
var getRows = this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
}
console.log("2"); //Print 2

if (getRows.err) {
    // Handle error
    console.log(getRows.err);
} else {
    const numRows = getRows.result.values ? getRows.result.values.length : 0;
    console.log(`${numRows} rows retrieved.`);
    console.log("3") //Print 3
}
```

---

Edit:
I want the err outside of the scope so I can do somethng like this: (If the sheet call fails with code 429, the programm will sleep for 100sek and the try it again) pseudo code:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
var getRows = this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
}
console.log("2"); //Print 2

if (getRows.err) {
    // Handle error
    if(getRows.err.code === 429){
        console.log("Too many requests, try again in 100sek");
        await sleep(100000); //sleep function with 100sek
        continue
    }
    //Some other code here
} else {
    //logic for the results
    console.log("3") //Print 3
}
console.log("Finished");
}
```

So 123 will be correctly printed and if the call fails it will be retried after 100sek with maximal 5 tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `promises` instead of `callbacks` or `async/await`:

#### Snippet:

```
console.log("1");
var i = 0;
function loop(){
if( ++i > 5 ) return; 
this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
})
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
    console.log("2");
})
.then(()=>console.log("3"))
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err);
  if(err.code === 429){
     sleep(100000).then(loop) 
  }
})
}
```

#### References:

- [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Creating_a_Promise_around_an_old_callback_API)
- [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [Nodejs client example](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/README.md#first-example)

Comment: Mh, I want to have this inside of a for loop and if I get a error code 429 back, I would sleep for 100sek and then `continue` so I get back to the beginning and try it again. Would this be possible with this setup? (Maybe I should include that in my question)

Comment: @Take You can try `async/await` instead of promises or you can run the function recursively

Comment: I really cant do my function recursive. I cant understand how I can make it async/await inside a for loop so I can `continue` when I get the error code.

Comment: @Take why can't you make the function recursive as shown above?

Comment: Ok after looking into async/await again and some trial and error I noticed that I can just do that: `var result = await this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
  spreadsheetId,
  range,
})
` and this code goes into a try catch block, if a error occurred, I can handle it in the catch block. That's works for me. And for recursive, I also have a bit more code in the function so I would need to modify a bit to make it possible.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution:

```
async function GetData() {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        try {
            var data = await this.sheetsService.spreadsheets.values.get({
                spreadsheetId,
                range
            });
            return data;
        } catch (err) {
            if (err.code === 429) {
                console.log("Too many requests, try again in 100sek");
                await sleep(100000); //sleep function with 100sek
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```